# Can't access parent $scope in $mdBottomSheet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, bottom-sheet

I can't access the parent ä`$scope` in my `$mdBottomSheet`. Iwant be able to create this bottom sheet and click one of the buttons inside of it displaying the parent `$scope` data. I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/end_game/pen/aqVqaB).

**That's the code by the way:**

```
<div ng-controller="BottomSheetExample" class="md-padding bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">

  <div class="bottom-sheet-demo inset" layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center">

    <md-button flex="50" class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showGridBottomSheet()">Show as Grid</md-button>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="alert">
    <br>
    <b layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="md-padding">
      {{alert}}
    </b>
  </div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="bottom-sheet-grid-template.html"><md-bottom-sheet class="md-grid" layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <div>
    <md-list flex layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div>
        <md-button class="md-grid-item-content" ng-click="listItemClick($index)">
          <md-icon md-svg-src="{{item.icon}}"></md-icon>
          <div class="md-grid-text"> {{ item.name }} </div>
        </md-button>
        </div>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </div>
</md-bottom-sheet>
</script>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
.config(function($mdIconProvider) {
    $mdIconProvider
      .icon('share-arrow', 'img/icons/share-arrow.svg', 24)
      .icon('upload', 'img/icons/upload.svg', 24)
      .icon('copy', 'img/icons/copy.svg', 24)
      .icon('print', 'img/icons/print.svg', 24)
      .icon('hangout', 'img/icons/hangout.svg', 24)
      .icon('mail', 'img/icons/mail.svg', 24)
      .icon('message', 'img/icons/message.svg', 24)
      .icon('copy2', 'img/icons/copy2.svg', 24)
      .icon('facebook', 'img/icons/facebook.svg', 24)
      .icon('twitter', 'img/icons/twitter.svg', 24);
  })
.controller('BottomSheetExample', function($scope, $timeout, $mdBottomSheet, $mdToast) {
  $scope.alert = '';
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Hangout', icon: 'hangout' },
    { name: 'Mail', icon: 'mail' },
    { name: 'Message', icon: 'message' },
    { name: 'Copy', icon: 'copy2' },
    { name: 'Facebook', icon: 'facebook' },
    { name: 'Twitter', icon: 'twitter' },
  ];

  $scope.listItemClick = function($index) {
    var clickedItem = $scope.items[$index];
    $mdBottomSheet.hide(clickedItem);
  };
  $scope.showGridBottomSheet = function() {
    $scope.alert = '';
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
      templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-grid-template.html',
      controller: function () {
                      return this;
      },
      preserveScope: true,
      bindToController: true,
      clickOutsideToClose: true
    }).then(function(clickedItem) {
      $mdToast.show(
            $mdToast.simple()
              .textContent(clickedItem['name'] + ' clicked!')
              .position('top right')
              .hideDelay(1500)
          );
    });
  };
})
.run(function($http, $templateCache) {

    var urls = [
      'img/icons/share-arrow.svg',
      'img/icons/upload.svg',
      'img/icons/copy.svg',
      'img/icons/print.svg',
      'img/icons/hangout.svg',
      'img/icons/mail.svg',
      'img/icons/message.svg',
      'img/icons/copy2.svg',
      'img/icons/facebook.svg',
      'img/icons/twitter.svg'
    ];

    angular.forEach(urls, function(url) {
      $http.get(url, {cache: $templateCache});
    });

  });
```

I can't see the buttons/icons inside the sheet.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvkr9zwe/

Comment: How is possible? i can see it

Comment: I added a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uvkr9zwe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse your parent controller scope in the right way by instancing and referencing the parent controller scope.

Check this **[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wveq0zjz/9/)**:

**Your scope Action:**

```
.controller('BottomSheetExample', function($scope, $timeout, $mdBottomSheet, $mdToast) {

  $scope.alert = '';

  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Hangout', icon: 'hangout' },
    { name: 'Mail', icon: 'mail' },
    { name: 'Message', icon: 'message' },
    { name: 'Copy', icon: 'copy2' },
    { name: 'Facebook', icon: 'facebook' },
    { name: 'Twitter', icon: 'twitter' },
  ];

  $scope.showGridBottomSheet = function() {
      $mdBottomSheet.show({
        templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-grid-template',
        controller: function () {
           this.parent = $scope;
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        clickOutsideToClose: true
      }).then(function(clickedItem) {
        $mdToast.show(
              $mdToast.simple()
                .textContent(clickedItem['name'] + ' clicked!')
                .position('top right')
                .hideDelay(1500)
            );
      });
    };
})
```

**View Template:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="bottom-sheet-grid-template">
  <md-bottom-sheet class="md-grid" layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <div>
    <md-list flex layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in ctrl.parent.items">
        <div>
        <md-button class="md-grid-item-content" ng-click="listItemClick($index)">
          <md-icon md-svg-src="{{item.icon}}"></md-icon>
          <div class="md-grid-text"> {{ item.name }} </div>
        </md-button>
        </div>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </div>
</md-bottom-sheet>
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, now I can see the buttons, but if click it seems that the function listItemClick() not working

Comment: @End.Game you need to access the controller scope. Please read this answer carefully. Try it with `ng-click="ctr.parent.listItemClick($index)"`. I also updated my fiddle example. Please check it. The click is working.

Comment: Please check my demo. The `listItemClick()` is executed.

Comment: Ok, I get it now! Thank you very much!